# I am not able to give permission to created folder in google drive using google drive APIs

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client, google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I have been trying to create a folder with a service account using google drive APIs in google drive. I can see that folder in the google folder list API but not in the google drive GUI.

Here is the code which I tried to create a google drive folder

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis');
require('dotenv').config();
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = process.env.CREDENTIALS_PATH

const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
module.exports = {
    createFolder: async () => {
        const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
            scopes: scopes,
            keyFilename: CREDENTIALS_PATH 
        })
        const service = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: auth });

        const fileMetadata = {
            name: 'newFolder',
            mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
        };

        try {
            const file = await service.files.create({
                requestBody: fileMetadata,
                fields: 'id',
            });

            if (!file.data.id) return;
            const res2 = await service.permissions
                .create({
                    resource: {
                        role: "owner",
                        type: "user",
                        emailAddress: email, 
                    },
                    fileId: file.data.id,
                    transferOwnership: true,
                    supportsAllDrives: true
                }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
            console.log(res2.data);

            return file.data.id;
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }

}
```

When I give permission to open a folder in drive then it throws an error.

Please find the below error:

```js
GaxiosError: Bad Request. User message: "You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as 
  response: {
    config: {
      url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/15NJCr03yIXZ5Sv-xwK3ZiuW0UFTIk4IM/permissions?fields=%2A&transferOwnership=true&moveToNewOwnersRoot=true',
      method: 'POST',
      userAgentDirectives: [Array],
      paramsSerializer: [Function (anonymous)],
      data: [Object],
      headers: [Object],
      params: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],
      retry: true,
      body: '{"type":"user","role":"owner","emailAddress":"########"}',
      responseType: 'json',
      retryConfig: [Object]
    },
    data: { error: [Object] },
    headers: {
      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"',
      'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
      connection: 'close',
      'content-encoding': 'gzip',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      server: 'ESF',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      vary: 'Origin, X-Origin',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-xss-protection': '0'
    },
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    request: {
      responseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/15NJCr03yIXZ5Sv-xwK3ZiuW0UFTIk4IM/permissions?fields=%2A&transferOwnership=true&moveToNewOwnersRoot=true'
    }
  },
  config: {
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/15NJCr03yIXZ5Sv-xwK3ZiuW0UFTIk4IM/permissions?fields=%2A&transferOwnership=true&moveToNewOwnersRoot=true',
    method: 'POST',
    userAgentDirectives: [ [Object] ],
    paramsSerializer: [Function (anonymous)],
    data: {
      type: 'user',
      role: 'owner',
      emailAddress: '#########'
    },
    headers: {
      'x-goog-api-client': 'gdcl/6.0.3 gl-node/18.5.0 auth/8.7.0',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
      'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/6.0.3 (gzip)',
      Authorization: 'Bearer #############################################',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    params: { fields: '*', transferOwnership: true, moveToNewOwnersRoot: true },
    validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],
    retry: true,
    body: '{"type":"user","role":"owner","emailAddress":"##############"}',
    responseType: 'json',
    retryConfig: {
      currentRetryAttempt: 0,
      retry: 3,
      httpMethodsToRetry: [Array],
      noResponseRetries: 2,
      statusCodesToRetry: [Array]
    }
  },
  code: 400,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Bad Request. User message: "You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate."',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'invalidSharingRequest'
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you please help me to find that folder in google drive using google drive API?